# Can I replace a Core 2 Duo with a Core 2 Quad processor?

Tags: intel-core2

Can a Core 2 Quad processor be a direct replacement for a Core 2 Duo, given the same socket arrangement?

Answer (score 4):

If they have the same socket type (i.e. Socket 775) then a Core 2 Quad should work in place of a Core 2 Duo.  At worst it may be a bios upgrade is necessary but other than that it should just work.

Comment: Search your motherboard's site to verify that it will work.  Some of the original boards still only will support C2D and not C2Q chips...

Comment: Another thing to remember is that the TDP of the quad core models is often 95W where the dual cores are 65W, which may cause issues with power or heat.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your motherboard and your BIOS. We need more specifics to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your motherboard. Please give us your motherboard's detailed information. It depends on the chipset also and some motherboards won't even support it with a bios upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Most C2Ds and C2Qs are directly replacable, if they're from the same generation (E/Q 6xxx, E/Q9xxx). However, your motherboard may differ and the only way to be certain is to check the manual.